# Arithmetic on bucket results

Tags: elasticsearch

So I am creating 2 buckets, Sale and Rent and I'd like to calculate their ratio but I'm unable to do so.

```
{
"size":"0",
"query":{
    "filtered":{
        "filter":{
                    "term":{"area":"Ireland"}
                 }
               }
        },
"aggs":{
"Sale":{"filter":{"term":{"type":"sale"}}, "aggs":{"price":{"percentiles":{"field":"price", "percents":[75]}}}}, 
"Rent":{"filter":{"term":{"type":"rent"}}, "aggs":{"price":{"percentiles":{"field":"price", "percents":[75]}}}}
}}
```

Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at the moment, with Elasticsearch.

But it's being actively implemented and tracked in [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110).